# Central Web Proxy vs Endpoint Protection

Tags: proxy, tls-intercept

Imagine the following imaginary scenarios:

1. In order to browse the Internet, users must go through a central web proxy. It is authenticated and can enforce rules about who can access which URLs or which file types are okay to download. At the same time, it is configured to use TLS inspection to scan downloads for malware. The proxy cannot be bypassed in this scenario.
2. On all clients and servers an AV/EDR software is installed, which can also do TLS inspection and can also decide based on the logged in user, who can access which URL and if a download contains malware. A central proxy is not used in this case.

What do you see as the (security) benefits of both options or should they be combined and if so, in what cases? If you have a lot of distributed employees (due to home office, multiple locations or users always in motion), you would have to route everything through a VPN at all times in the case of the proxy, or use a cloud proxy like ZScaler.

One advantage of having a proxy would be that it can also protect devices that don't have such software running for whatever reason. A proxy introduces more complexity in my opinion and is usually an overkill for a small company.